# Unexpected convert numeric to string on object create in typescript

Tags: angular, string, typescript, numeric, converters

I write an service on Angular.
Declare variable in service class:

```
private tariffCache: {id: number, observable: Observable<Tariff>}[] = [];
```

(attention to id)

Fill out this variable in function:

```
getTariff(id: number): Observable<Tariff> {
    if (!this.tariffCache || !this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === id)) {
      const url = ${this.tariffsUrl}/${id};
      this.tariffCache.push({
        id,
        observable: this.http.get<Tariff>(url, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(shareReplay(1))
      });
    }
    return this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === id).observable;
  }
```

What I expect to see in variable 'tariffCache' after response from server with id = 34?

```
{id: 34, observable: Observable}
```

Right! But in fact:

```
{id: "34", observable: Observable}
```

Wow? Why 34 now is string?! When it convert to string?! But is no all!
I repeat call this function with id = 34. 34 is numeric else compiler raise an error. All code in function 'getTariff' is work! Function 'find' is work fine with compare operator "===". Array contain object with string id and find element with numeric id. Brrrr...

I write other function with same code with function 'find' and it not work. What? Why not now?

Ok, I change function getTariff to:

```
getTariff(id: number): Observable<Tariff> {
    if (!this.tariffCache || !this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === +id)) {
      const url = ${this.tariffsUrl}/${id};
      this.tariffCache.push({
        id: +id,
        observable: this.http.get<Tariff>(url, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(shareReplay(1))
      });
    }
    return this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === +id).observable;
  }
```

And now array contain object with numeric id and other functions work with array too.
Can someone explain this behavior of 'id' and 'find'?
Thanks.

UPD:
Function 'getTariff' call from function 'changeCurrentTariff' in service. Function 'clearTariff' is not worked, before change 'getTariff'. This is fragment of code in service:

```
export class TariffService extends AbstractModelService {
  private tariffsUrl = environment.baseUrl + 'api/Tariffs';
  private tariffCache: {id: number, observable: Observable<Tariff>}[] = [];
  private tariffSource = new BehaviorSubject<Tariff>(null);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super();
  }
  currentTariff = this.tariffSource.asObservable();
  changeCurrentTariff(id: number) {
    if (id) {
      this.getTariff(id)
        .subscribe(tariff => {
          this.tariffSource.next(tariff);
        });
    }
  }
  /** GET tariff by id. Will 404 if id not found */
  getTariff(id: number): Observable<Tariff> {
    if (!this.tariffCache || !this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === +id)) {
      const url = `${this.tariffsUrl}/${id}`;
      this.tariffCache.push({
        id: +id,
        observable: this.http.get<Tariff>(url, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(shareReplay(1))
      });
    }
    return this.tariffCache.find(x => x.id === +id).observable;
  }
  clearTariff(id: number) {
    if (this.tariffCache) {
      const index = this.tariffCache.findIndex(x => x.id === +id);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.tariffCache.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But 'changeCurrentTariff' call from component:

```
export class TariffComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private tariffService: TariffService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
        )
        .subscribe(params => {
          if (params.id) {
            this.tariffService.changeCurrentTariff(params.id);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: But how is `getTariff` called? Insert a log point with `typeof id` there and see whether that's string or number.

Comment: do you have control over the server response? this could be a back end issue with typing /serialisation

Comment: @mbojko, if I call getTariff with string argument, Typescript must raise error?

Comment: If it somehow gets past type checking at build time, then at runtime there's no TypeScript there to raise errors. Just pure JavaScript.

Comment: @mbojko there are not errors in debug and runtime mode. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK route params are always parsed as strings, so here

```
    this.route.params
        .pipe(
          takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
        )
        .subscribe(params => {
          if (params.id) {
```

you'll need to explicitly convert `id` to number.

Comment: Ok, but why code is not fail in this place with error? Function is declared with id: number! I must check types of declared arguments always?

Comment: That's an Angular thing: they type route params as `[key: string]: any;`.

Comment: Anyhow, I don't understand, why Angular or Typescript in debug mode do not raise error on call function getTariff with string argument params.id. Illogical! Declare type of function argument and not check input argument type. :(

Comment: Because as soon as you build it and get it running (and in developer mode TS is even more forgiving than in production mode), type declarations are irrelevant. The browser runs transpiled JavaScript (with no type declarations), not TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
There is no happiness in life